# How to remove nodes with java API for graphstream?

Tags: java, nodes, graphstream

I currently use the Graphstream API for Java for my project.

I wan't to delete or add Nodes on command.
With JFrame & co. I initialized a console so I can just insert
"addNode()" or "removeNode(id)" in order to get the result.

A Interface shows the nodes with a number next to them(the ID).

When I delete one node, I want all nodes with higher ID to change their ID,
but I did not figure out a way jet to change the ID of one node.

F.e. I have:

```
    graph.addNode(0);
    graph.addNode(1);
    graph.addNode(2);
```

When deleting a Node:

```
    graph.removeNode(0);
```

I want 1,2 to be changed to 0,1 without reinitializing the complete graph.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour? I thought about something like:

```
    graph.getNode(1).setID(0);
```

Unfortunately I have only access to .getID() and can't manipulate it this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodes ids are strings and they are immutable (no renaming, no `setId()`).

Now what you are doing in your example is different. You are using the index-based access to the nodes. Indices are integers and correspond to arbitrary nodes in the graph, they are not associated to the ids.

When you do `graph.addNode(0)`, the integer is converted to the  **string** `"0"`. Then when you do graph.removeNode(0), you are removing a node that was indexed as the first of the list of nodes. But it does have to be the node this id `"0"`.

You can remove nodes with index (integer) 0 as long as there are nodes in the graph (`graph.removeNode(0)`) but you can only remove the one node with id `"0"` once (`graph.removeNode("0")`).

Comment: Thanks, I do understand this behaviour given by graphstream nodes.